# Flexibility of map-reduce in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

The [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) says about map-reduce:

*For most aggregation operations, the Aggregation Pipeline provides better performance and more coherent interface. However, map-reduce operations provide some flexibility that is not presently available in the aggregation pipeline.*

Does it mean that there are some aggregation operations that cannot be performed in the usual MongoDB aggregation framework but are possible using map-reduce?

In particular I'm looking for an example of map-reduce that cannot be implemented in the MongoDB aggregation framework

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725560/grouping-documents-in-pairs-using-mongo-aggregation) of "flexibility". Basically, if you have any logic, that does not fit into [standard aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), map-reduce is the only option to do it serverside.